# Decrypt Shared Secret in Identity Server

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using Identity Server and I lost one secret, and now I only have the hash

its anyway to obtain the original secret having the shared secret and hash of SHA256?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best tool in the industry to crack a hash is to use [HashCat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/), but depending on the hash algorithm used, it might take quite some time.